# Mongoose orderby not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a simple db to store the highscore of a game.
Now I would like to retrieve the highscore as sorted list.
Unfortunately I can't figure out why the following code won't work, the returned list is not sorted by the score property.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Score = mongoose.model('Score');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Score.find( { $query: {}, $orderby: { score : -1 } } , function(err, scores) {
    if (err) {return next(err);}
    res.json(scores);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$orderBy` is [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/) try using `.sort()`

```
Score.find( {}).sort( { score : -1 } }).exec(function(err, scores) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

`$orderBy` is deprecated try this..

```
mongoose.model('modelName').find().sort({ name: 'asc' }).exec(function(err, con) {
            console.log(con);

    });
```